# JSF p:remoteCommand and javascript event onbeforeunload

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, internet-explorer-9, java-ee-6, onbeforeunload

We have several web applications a user can login. On click on logout button some logic must be processed. The problem is that most users close the browser without clicking on logout button. I tried the following to call my logic on browser close:

1. Added the event "onbeforeunload" to my frameset. On browser close a logout function will be called.
2. Within my logout function I use the primefaces p:remoteCommand component to call a action listener on the server.

In current firefox version everything works fine but I have some problems with IE9. Closing a tab in IE9 calls my logic. Closing the browser doesn´t work. My JS function is called but the request to the server is not executed. Is there any way to solve this problem? BTW: I know that this is not an 100% solution but we need exactly this functionality. My function and p:remoteCommand looks like that.

```
function automaticLogout() {
    handleAutomaticLogout();
    alert('BlaBla');
}

<p:remoteCommand name="handleAutomaticLogout" actionListener="#{myBean.handleAutomaticLogout}" async="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically require a client-side Javascript solution or is this just the way you have gone about it so far?

On the Server Side, placing a `@PreDestroy` annotation above a Backing Bean method causes that method to be invoked just before the Bean goes out of scope.

If you write a method which [invalidates the session](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/releasing_and_invalidating_httpsessions.html) (`session.invalidate()`) with this annotation, it will be called when the user leaves your page without clicking Log Out.

**Backing Bean:**

```
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PreDestroyBean {

    //Called by button - log out perhaps?
    public void killTheSessionDeliberately() {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        session.invalidate();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void revokeLicense() {
        System.out.println("PreDestroy method was called.");

    }
}
```

**Page Button:**

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="killSession" value="Kill Session" 
            actionListener="#{preDestroyBean.killTheSessionDeliberately()}" update="@form" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: My current case is that I must release requested licenses on logout. Our session timeout is 30Min, but the license must be released directly after a user leaves the app. I´m not sure, but I think the @PreDestroy solution works only if session expires?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean -  my apologies, the @PreDestroy needs the Session to be destroyed in order to fire. Fusing the two approaches, a Javascript call (on body unload) to the Session destroy method via something like a PrimeFaces RemoteCommand (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) may allow you to immediately invalidate the user's session when they leave ( http://www.coderanch.com/t/384874/java/java/destroying-session-when-user-closes) and cause the License Revoke method to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use p:remoteCommand along with  onunload. 
example:

```
<body onunload="test();"> 
    <form id="exit">
       <p:remoteCommand  id="test" name="test" action="#{ContatoMB.teste}"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

referencing http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15695
 It works for me.